# db2 query condition where column not in () while the column value is null

Tags: sql, null, db2, where-in

Good day,

I have a row of data with a column, call status, the value inside is null.

If I query `select * from table where status not in ('EXP')`, before I run this query, I thought I can select the row of data because `status=null`, consider `not in ('EXP')` also. After I tried, I found that I cant query out this row of data. Wish to know why this happen.

Try to Google it but maybe my question is not correct so I cant get correct search result from Google.

Kindly advise.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Please take care when tagging your questions.

Comment: Have you tried `select * from table where status != 'EXP'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NULL values are only checked with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE status NOT IN ('EXP')
    OR status IS NULL;
```

Hope I have understand your question.

Maybe the other way around

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE status NOT IN ('EXP')
   AND status IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: ya, understand what you means. so the `NULL` values are `ONLY` checked with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.